# Stata - calculating a value for expected lifetime value using a cumulative sum

Tags: stata

I am trying to calculate the expected lifetime income of individuals. The formula I need to use is the following:

E[Lifetime] = S + S/[(1+r1)] + S/[(1+r1)(1+r2)] + .... + S/[(1+r1)..(1+rn)]

Here, r1...rn are interest rates for every year the individual is alive, and S is the income of the individual. My problem is that I have a dataset which contains S for every individual and their year of death. Now, using these two numbers, I need to calculate E[lifetime] for all individuals. I have the r's for all years, of course. How do I calculate this in Stata?

The problem is that the number of r's in the formula depends on the number of years the individual lives, and to make things more complicated, each 'r' is different! I have a huge dataset so I can't calculate this for every individual mechanically. Please help!

I tried a for loop, but again, the problem is that the number of terms in the formula is different for every individual.

EDIT: My dataset looks something like this:

```
ID    Base Year    Income    Death Year
---------------------------------------
1        1975       1000       2008
2        1978       2423       2005
3        1980       1982       2010
4        1975       1093       2002
5        1976       4382       1999
6        1981       5492       2005
7        1978       1743       1995
```

I also have a vector of "r" for all years from 1970 to 2010. Now, the calculation I would need to perform for the first person is:

E[lifetime] = 1000 + 1000/(1+r1976) + 1000/(1+r1976)(1+r1977) +

... + 1000/(1+r1976)(1+r1977)...(1+r2008)

Comment: It would help if you clarify what your data looks like.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope this clarifies things @DimitriyV.Masterov

Comment: It's still not clear how r is stored.

Comment: r is not stored. i have the r values corresponding to each year, though. i can make a vector of r's, as one would in Python, but I'm not sure that's possible in Stata? I can also store the r's in columns, i.e., one column which would be constant r1975 for each ID, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do this assuming the interest rates for each year are in a separate file. The main tricks are

1. reshape the data to be in long format and fill in the years between
   base year and death year for each person.
2. To get the discount factors, calculate the running sum of logged 1/(1+rn) terms and then exponentiating that to get the running product of the discount factors.

Here's the Stata code:

```
/* Create a dataset of interest rates */
clear
set obs 36
gen year= 1974 +_n
set seed 1234
gen r=uniform()/10
tempfile interest_rates
save `interest_rates'

/* Fake Income data */
clear
input id    base_year    income    death_year
1        1975       1000       2008
2        1978       2423       2005
3        1980       1982       2010
4        1975       1093       2002
5        1976       4382       1999
6        1981       5492       2005
7        1978       1743       1995
8        2008       59        2010  
end

rename base_year  year0
rename death_year year1

reshape long year, i(id income) j(time)
drop time
xtset id year
tsfill
capture ssc install carryforward
bysort id: carryforward income, replace

merge m:1 year using `interest_rates', keep(match) nogen

bysort id (year): replace r=0 if _n==1 // don't discount at t=1
bysort id (year): gen dfactor = sum(ln(1/(1+r)))
bysort id (year): replace dfactor = exp(dfactor)

gen double disc_income = income * dfactor  

collapse (sum) exp_income = disc_income, by(id)
```

For example, obs 8 (which I added) had an income of 59 from 2008 to 2010, so that should be

```
. di 59 + 59/(1+.0084592)+59/((1+.0084592)*(1+.0834539))
171.50379
```